# Unable to access AWS in China Region without a Web Proxy

Tags: networking, ssh, firefox, vpn, proxy

I have Verizon FIOS for an ISP.

I am not able to access any **amazon.com.cn** domains from my home office in Boston, MA except through a web proxy plugin on FireFox.

With that https/sockv5 proxy, the web traffic generated by the browser is routed to Indiana, and from there to China and I am able to see the AWS console.

But that's really not enough.  I need to be able to SSH into instances, and use the CLI, etc.

By the logic of the proxy, I thought if I setup a VPN tunnel, then I can go around this.

I signed up for a 1 month subscription with ExpressVPN.  Setup is quite simple and I confirmed that all routes are going through **tun0**

```
$ ip route show
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.28.86.85 dev tun0
```

Also confirmed I have a different IP address than what Verizon FIOS gives me.

But still, with just the VPN, I am not able to connect to any AWS China addresses.

I did a **traceroute** several times on this, and here is what I am getting:

```
traceroute console.amazonaws.cn
traceroute to console.amazonaws.cn (54.222.6.129), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.28.0.1 (10.28.0.1)  18.923 ms  18.903 ms  19.141 ms
 2  91.fc.2bd0.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com (208.43.252.145)  24.421 ms  24.456 ms  24.454 ms
 3  ae14.dar01.wdc01.networklayer.com (208.43.118.160)  24.389 ms  24.389 ms  24.028 ms
 4  ae8.bbr01.eq01.wdc02.networklayer.com (173.192.18.196)  24.658 ms  24.660 ms ae8.bbr02.eq01.wdc02.networklayer.com (173.192.18.192)  24.371 ms
 5  lag-197.bear1.Washington111.Level3.net (4.53.112.25)  24.373 ms  25.044 ms  28.963 ms
 6  * * *
 7  CHINA-TELEC.ear1.LosAngeles1.Level3.net (4.35.156.114)  98.413 ms CHINA-TELEC.ear1.LosAngeles1.Level3.net (4.35.156.10)  95.785 ms CHINA-TELEC.ear1.LosAngeles1.Level3.net (4.35.157.250)  97.167 ms
 8  202.97.50.29 (202.97.50.29)  91.601 ms  91.606 ms  91.918 ms
 9  202.97.58.125 (202.97.58.125)  468.594 ms  468.614 ms *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
.....
```

I had a colleague in Indiana run a similar one and here is his output

[image]

Lastly, I spent several hours on the phone with Verizon FIOS support and long story short, they filed a **backlog** ticket with the network engineers, who **confirmed** whatever the problem is, it's not on their end.  The usual pass the ball crap.

**Anyone have an idea of what I can try next?**

Comment: Yes, contact Amazon. Obviously your IP address or provider is blacklisted. It's China.

Comment: Already did, they suggested to contact my ISP :)

Comment: Yes, Well I would suggest you contact China and complain, but that obviously isn’t possible.  So move your AWS instance instead

Comment: I wish you could down vote a comment! Do you really think that's an option!!!

Comment: Commercial VPNs are likely to be blocked by the chinese firewall. Just like public proxies. Why not tunnel ssh through the Indiana proxy that works? SOCKSv5 proxy should be able to proxy all TCP traffic.Have you tried answers in here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19161960 ?

Comment: The `aws` CLI utility even has documentation how to make it use HTTP proxy: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-http-proxy.html you tried that as well?

Comment: @MarekRost Thanks! This is great information! I am going to try both these approaches today and report back here.